# How to solution this problem in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:\AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 Error:
    Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) from [com.android.support:design:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.0.1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) from [com.android.support:design:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
  >   is also present at [com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.0.1).
  >   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 26s

Comment: please post your manifest, especially line 28 
and also format your error code correctly

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened because of mess in libraries.
You have two libraries in your project com.android.support.design and `com.android.support.customtabs` both have conflict. Both are using value and build system is not able to understand which one should use.
To resolve this issue just add

> `tools:replace="android:value"`

in application tag of your manifest.

You can also check details by opening manifest file and here below you will find tab merge manifest. By click on it you can check details of manifests of libraries you are using in your project.